# Can't always detect last date in python

Tags: python

I have some code created in python and I need it to always detect the last date of the JSON of the fortnite API, how can I do it?

[image: data]

```
response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")



fecha = isoparse(response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']).timestamp()

timestamp = fecha


date1 =  parser.parse(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
date2 = datetime.now()
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
r.months + (12*r.years)


print(max(r.days))
```

I did it with a "max" but the result does not appear

Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

I must count the days elapsed from the last date to the current one

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: What does the result of the request look like when you get the error?

Comment: @itprorh66 https://i.imgur.com/lWJ4M4Y.png

Answer (score 0):

Api gives list of date strings. You can try this:

```py
import requests, time
import dateutil.parser as dp

response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")

lss = response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']

lss.sort()

lastTs = dp.isoparse(lss[-1]).timestamp()
currTs = time.time()

deltaDays = (currTs - lastTs) / (60*60*24)

print( str(round(deltaDays)) + " days" )
```